# How to Show the Layout when click on pushpin in bingmaps?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Based on Lat,lon values displaying the pushpin in bing maps.I need to show the layout like username,useraddress,one side arrow and one close button  .when click on pushpin need to show that layout.please help me ..

thanks in advance..

Comment: i am new to this.please tell me any samples on that...

Answer (score 0):

Bing maps control accepts any UIElement as a child so you can use a UserControl.

Create a User control with layout you need. Then you can connect the tap event to a change in the visualstate of the control.

Comment: Created the usercontrol .but how to show that layout when click on tap in pushpin on bing maps?any samples please let me know..

Comment: Any samples on that please let me know.