# Samples on Pushpin infobox in windows phone 7 bing maps?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to show the info box when click on pushpins in windows phone 7?i.e when click on pushpin need to show some data and arrow button on the right side of data.please help me ...

Comment: As of now i am displaying the pushpin on map.but how to show that infobox when click on that?

Comment: Try http://igrali.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Show the Layout when click on pushpin in bingmaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793881/how-to-show-the-layout-when-click-on-pushpin-in-bingmaps)

Comment: Why did you open 2 new questions for that?

Answer (score 1):

when you click on pushpin at that time you display message box.
i.e In Your click event put message box.see bellow coding

```
                        pin[i] = new Pushpin();
                        pin[i].Location = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, LongLatitude);

                        map1.Children.Add(pin[i]);
                        myCoorditeWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                        myCoorditeWatcher.MovementThreshold = 20;

                        var gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(pin[i]);
                        gl.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(GestureListener_Stack_Tap);




 private void GestureListener_Stack_Tap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLongLatitude.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (sender.Equals(pin[i]))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLocationName.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim());
                                        MessageBox.Show(ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLatitude.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim());
                    MessageBox.Show(ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLongLatitude.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim());

                }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Pushpin

for example :

```
<my:Map Name="map1">

                <my:Map.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="pushpinTpl">
                        <my:Pushpin PositionOrigin="{Binding position}">
                            <my:Pushpin.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="togButt" >
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="click" 
                                                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=togButt,Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter},ConverterParameter=!}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="alternative content" 
                                                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=togButt,Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </my:Pushpin.ContentTemplate>
                        </my:Pushpin>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:Map.Resources>

                <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding items}" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pushpinTpl}"
                                    />
            </my:Map>
```

hope this help :)

Comment: Sorry @Dargos i am not getting can you give some sample on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of examples on the Bind sdk site:
http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7